# dynamic HREF attribute by XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

Can anyone plese advice how I can have dynamic HREF attribute in the place of ʜᴛᴛᴘ://abc.com by XSLT in following code snippet?

```
<xsl:for-each select="MenuItems/mainmenu">
    <a href="ʜᴛᴛᴘ://abc.com">
       <span><xsl:value-of select="menuName"/></span>
    </a>   
</xsl:for-each>
```

sample xml

```
<MenuItems>
<mainmenu>
    <menuID>1</menuID>
    <menuName>Home</menuName>
    <menuLink>http://aaa.com</menuLink>
        <subMenuList>
            <menuID>2</menuID>
            <menuName>Home</menuName>
            <menuLink>http://a1.com</menuLink>
        </subMenuList>
        <subMenuList>
            <menuID>3</menuID>
            <menuName>List of RCCs</menuName>
            <menuLink>http://a2.com</menuLink>
        </subMenuList>
        <subMenuList>
        <menuID>4</menuID>
        <menuName>Turnover Workout</menuName>
        <menuLink>http://a3.com</menuLink>
        </subMenuList>
</mainmenu>
<MenuItems>
```

Comment: in my XML file I have hrefs like following...        <menuID>1</menuID>
         <menuName>Home</menuName>
         <menuLink>http://abc.com</menuLink>

Comment: Please post some sample input XML and desired output.

Comment: <MenuItems>
<mainmenu>
 <menuID>1</menuID>
 <menuName>Home</menuName>
 <menuLink>http://aaa.com</menuLink>
  <subMenuList>
   <menuID>2</menuID>
   <menuName>Home</menuName>
   <menuLink>http://a1.com</menuLink>
  </subMenuList>
  <subMenuList>
   <menuID>3</menuID>
   <menuName>List of RCCs</menuName>
   <menuLink>http://a2.com</menuLink>
  </subMenuList>
  <subMenuList>
  <menuID>4</menuID>
  <menuName>Turnover Workout</menuName>
  <menuLink>http://a3.com</menuLink>
  </subMenuList>
</mainmenu>
<MenuItems>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the `<xsl:attribute>` element:

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="menuLink"/></xsl:attribute>
    <span><xsl:value-of select="menuName"/></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an attribute value template:

```
<a href="{menuLink}">
  <span><xsl:value-of select="menuName"/></span>
</a>
```